# How to change the default application icons of Gnome Shell's top right area

Tags: gnome, indicator, icons

Im using Gnome 3 with Gnome Shell, my problem is some of the applications that have indicators in the top right area dont have icons that fit with the others.

This is how my indicator icons look like:
[image]

I want if possible to find the skype and pidgin icons and replace them (i tried searching for pidgins with dpkg -L pidgin but didn't notice any icon-like extensions of the listed files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are from default placed at `/usr/share/icons/IconTheme/apps/XXX/`, where `IconTheme` is the icon theme that you are currently using (e.g. Faenza) and `XXX` the size of the icons.

It would be good to replace all of these icons to the ones you like. Be careful to keep backups, though, in case you are not sure that you want to do this. You can convert an image to many different sizes with the `convert` command of the imagemagick package:

```
convert 1.png -resize 100x100 2.png
```

Comment: awesome thank you
result: http://i.imgur.com/NVqJy.png

Comment: Very nice κύριε βαρεμένε :)